# iOS (swift) - custom view within a custom view controller XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a screen that has (among other things), a row of custom buttons. For ease of reuse, I have a custom class (xib and swift file) for the buttons (MyButton : UIView) and for the row of buttons (MyRowController : UIViewController). In MyRowController.xib, I have a row of buttons that have their "Custom Class" attribute set to MyButton. I am trying to add an instance of MyRowController to the screen (MyViewController : UIViewController), as so:

```
 let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyRowController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
 let row = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as MyRowController
 self.view.addSubview(row.view)
```

Unfortunately, this causes a crash in MyButton's awakeFromNib method:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
 @IBOutlet weak var grayBackgroundView: UIView!
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    grayBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 }
```

Apparently grayBackgroundView has not been instantiated when awakeFromNib is called (if I comment out the grayBackgroundView line, there is no crash, but none of the labels or images in my MyButton view are displayed). When I try to add MyButton directly to MyViewController (removing MyRowController as the middle man), everything works normally - no crash and all the labels/images appear normally.

I've also tried having MyRowController be a subclass of a UIView and the same thing happens.

I'm new to iOS, so if this is a non-standard/terrible way to reuse view, please let me know. I'm not sure if I should be doing something in MyRowController's initializer to help instantiate MyButtons (currently it does nothing other than call super.init(coder: aDecoder))?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!